# Find intersection, union and difference of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Find $A\cup B, A\cap B, A\setminus B$ and $B\setminus A$ for the following sets: $A=\{x\in \Bbb R: -2x+5>0\}$ and $B=\{x\in \Bbb R: \frac{1}{x}< 1\}$

I'm not sure whether my solution is correct:

$A=<-\infty, \frac{5}{2}>$, $B=<-\infty, 0>\cup <1,\infty>$

$A\cup B= \Bbb R$

$A\cap B=<-\infty, 0>\cup <1, \frac{5}{2}>$

$A\setminus B=[\,0,1]\,$

$B\setminus A=<\frac{5}{2}, \infty>$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is correct,
there's  only one mistake :

**B/A =  [5/2, ∞>**

Comment: To check your results write $A=(-\infty,0)\cup [0,1]\cup (1,5/2)$ and $B=(-\infty,0)\cup (1,5/2)\cup [5/2,\infty).$